# Как авторизоваться через c# + VkNet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vkontakte-api, vknet

Не могу получить информацию пользователя ВК без авторизации. Как сделать авторизацию на C#??

> VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException: "Метод 'account.getProfileInfo' нельзя вызывать без авторизации"

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var profileInfo = api.Account.GetProfileInfo();
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(profileInfo);
        }
```

находил авторизацию с id приложения, но мне нужно чтобы просто вводили логин и пароль в textboxы и все пахало по нажатию на кнопку

Comment: Предоставьте код пожалуйста, никто с колена писать вам не будет

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и _минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения _прямо в вопросе_. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: сделано и исправлено

Comment: А теперь пишем в гугле VkNet и попадаем на [официальный сайт](https://vknet.github.io/vk/), где видим прям в самом начале раздел `Авторизация` с одной единственной ссылкой [Authorize](https://vknet.github.io/vk/authorize/), где понятным языком написано как делать авторизацию и даже пример есть!

Comment: а без id приложения никак?

Comment: Вроде как нет. Таковы требования VK. Да и не вижу проблем в этом, создать приложение 2 секунды каждый может...